# Is there a quick way of extracting data over several years corresponding to today's date

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that has a date column that spans from 2014-01-01 to today 2021-04-29, and other  columns of associated data.

What I would like to do is filter for data for the current day and month across all years. So data for 04-29 is brought back for all years 2014 to 2021 on that particular day.

What would be the most efficient / tidiest way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this

```r
set.seed(2)
df <- data.frame(d = as.Date('2015-01-01') + sample(1:3000, 1000),
                 o = runif(1000))

head(df)
#>            d         o
#> 1 2017-09-02 0.1481156
#> 2 2016-12-11 0.3957168
#> 3 2022-09-23 0.2654405
#> 4 2016-02-21 0.3482240
#> 5 2016-01-28 0.6943241
#> 6 2015-10-01 0.5069469
library(lubridate)

#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union
df[month(df$d) == month(Sys.Date()) & day(df$d) == day(Sys.Date()),]
#>              d         o
#> 24  2016-04-29 0.2431883
#> 131 2017-04-29 0.9359659
#> 383 2022-04-29 0.2703415
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

`dplyr` method is similar

```
df %>% filter(month(d) == month(Sys.Date()) & day(d) == day(Sys.Date()))
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way of doing this using dplyr? I was thinking of somehting like this but didn't work df %>% filter(d == month(Sys.Date()) & d == day(Sys.Date()))